# What is a "Break Rotator" and "Make Rotator" in Unreal Engine 4?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So, I am beginner in Unreal Engine 4. I am having trouble understanding "Make Rotator" and "Break Rotator" on Movement Input of the character blueprint class. The original definition UE4 documentation has made me even more confused. Can anyone explain this in a simple way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `FRotator` (or just `Rotator` in BP) is Unreal's way of storing rotations.

Usually, there are two main ways rotations are represented in programs:

1. As three separate rotation values per-axis, which is called Euler rotation: one for how much you rotate on X, one for Y, one for Z. This is the "older" approach, and has its issues, mainly [gimbal lock](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zc8b2Jo7mno). Also, there's no standard, and different programs apply them in different orders (some programs do ZXY: Z first, X second, Y third, but other do XYZ etc).
2. To solve the issues with Euler rotations, another option is used, with four separate values: three values denote the axis of rotation, and another one denotes the angle. This axis-and-angle value is called a quaternion (beacuse it has four values, quat is four in latin). Since any unique rotation mathematically can be expressed as an axis and angle, quaternion rotations are free of gimbal lock, and aren't dependent on any order.

Unreal internally uses quaternions (`FQuat`), but they're a bit harder to explain and understand, than just three X Y Z rotations. Because of that, `FQuat` is only for C++, and on the Blueprint level the editor simply shows the rotation as three axis. That's what the `Rotator` is for.

When you `break` a rotator, you just separate out the three float values for the XYZ rotations. When you `make` a rotator out of three float values, it makes the rotation that would result from them.

These `break` and `make` nodes exist for many other types, like `FVector` (shown in BP as just Vector), FLinearColor (Linear Color), to easily make a more complicated thing, like a color or rotation, out of simple `float` values.

Having said this, since the `Rotator` really represents an axis and angle, it's better not to use the `make Rotator` node, but the `rotator from axis and angle` node.

Rotators are quite convenient, because there are many functions in Unreal to work with them, such as `Lerp (Rotator)` and others.

Answer (score 1):

Break Rotator : allows access to the elements of the rotator.

Make Rotator : Make a rotator with three values.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).